# pandas wide_to_long suffix parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about a parameter when using wide_to_long in pandas.
There is parameter called `suffix` that I do not understand.

In the documentation it says:

> suffix : str, default ‘\d+’
>
> A regular expression capturing the wanted suffixes. ‘\d+’ captures numeric suffixes. Suffixes with no numbers could be specified with the negated character class ‘\D+’. You can also further disambiguate suffixes, for example, if your wide variables are of the form Aone, Btwo,.., and you have an unrelated column Arating, you can ignore the last one by specifying suffix=’(!?one|two)’
>
> New in version 0.20.0.

Question: What can be used for suffix?

And I found someone uses suffix like this when using wide_to_long: `suffix='.'`
What does it do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR**: Regex capturing groups can be used for the suffix parameter.

The `suffix` parameter tells `pandas.wide_to_long` which columns it should include in the transformation based on the suffix after the stub.

The default behavior of wide to long assumes that your columns are labeled with **numbers** so for instance columns `A1, A2, A3, A4` will work fine without specifying the suffix parameter, while `Aone, Atwo, Athree, Afour` will fail.

As explained, it also has various other uses in the rare cases that your columns may be `A1, A2, A3, A4, A100`, and you don't want to actually include `A100` because it isn't actually related to the other `A#` columns.

Here are some illustrative examples.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'A_1': ['a', 'b'],
                  'A_2': ['aa', 'bb'], 'A_3': ['aaa', 'bbb'],
                  'A_person': ['Mike', 'Amy']})

pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='A_', i='id', j='num')
#       A_person   A_
#id num              
#1  1       Mike    a
#2  1        Amy    b
#1  2       Mike   aa
#2  2        Amy   bb
#1  3       Mike  aaa
#2  3        Amy  bbb
```

Because the default behavior is to only consider numbers, `'A_person'` was ignored. If you wanted to add that to the conversion, then you would use the `suffix` parameter. Let's tell it we want either numbers or words.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='A_', i='id', j='suffix', suffix='(\d+|\w+)')
#             A_
#id suffix         
#1  1          a
#2  1          b
#1  2         aa
#2  2         bb
#1  3        aaa
#2  3        bbb
#1  person  Mike
#2  person   Amy
```

Now if your `df` starts without numeric suffixes, you can take care of that with the suffix parameter too. The default call will fail because it expects numbers, but telling it to look for words gives you what you want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'A_one': ['a', 'b'],
                  'A_two': ['aa', 'bb'], 'A_three': ['aaa', 'bbb'],
                  'A_person': ['Mike', 'Amy']})

pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='A_', i='id', j='num')
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [A_three, A_person, A_one, A_two, A_]
#Index: []

pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='A_', i='id', j='suffix', suffix='\w+')
#             A_
#id suffix         
#1  one        a
#2  one        b
#1  person  Mike
#2  person   Amy
#1  three    aaa
#2  three    bbb
#1  two       aa
#2  two       bb
```

And if you don't want to include `A_person` you can tell the suffix parameter to only include certain stubs.

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='A_', i='id', j='num', suffix='(one|two|three)')
#         A_person   A_
#id num                
#1  one       Mike    a
#2  one        Amy    b
#1  three     Mike  aaa
#2  three      Amy  bbb
#1  two       Mike   aa
#2  two        Amy   bb
```

Basically, if you can capture it with regex, you can pass it to suffix to use only the columns you want.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, What a big help
To add on, do you know where I can get info about the expression that can be used in suffix like a vertical line for 'OR' and so on?

Comment: I found that if you put '.' for suffix, it basically includes everything
Thanks again haha