# pd.wide_to_long gives empty data frame when trying to convert long data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am the following dataframe called `new`:

```
    policy_rate2008-01-01  policy_rate2008-02-21  ...           ID   x
ID                                                ...                   
1                    10.0                   11.0  ...  48150000996   2.0
2                    10.0                   11.0  ...  60001024367   5.0
3                    10.0                   11.0  ...  58001020206   1.0
4                    10.0                   11.0  ...  57001015191  13.0
5                    10.0                   11.0  ...  51001004844  15.0
```

I want to convert it in `wide_to_long` format by the following comand:

```
pd.wide_to_long(new,['policy_rate','REER','inflation'],i="ID", j="year")
```

But output of this comand is empt dataframe with column names

the Full list of columns in dataframe new is :

```
Index(['policy_rate2008-01-01', 'policy_rate2008-02-21',
       'policy_rate2008-03-20', 'policy_rate2008-04-17',
       'policy_rate2008-05-15', 'policy_rate2008-06-26',
       'policy_rate2008-07-24', 'policy_rate2008-08-21',
       'policy_rate2008-09-11', 'policy_rate2008-10-16',
       ...
       'inflation2020-05-29', 'inflation2020-06-24', 'inflation2020-07-29',
       'inflation2020-08-05', 'inflation2020-09-16', 'inflation2020-10-28',
       'inflation2020-11-29', 'inflation2020-12-09', 'ID', 'x'],
      dtype='object', length=470)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160774/pandas-wide-to-long-suffix-parameter. By default `wide_to_long` expect a purely numeric suffix. That's not the case as `2008-01-01` isn't a number. So you'll need to specify the suffix, probably with a `suffix='.*'`

Comment: @ALollz Thanks, I wrote it as the number ex.200801 (I discarded last terms), but now this code gives the same value, I mean in my code new time series name is 'year', but now it has just same value "200801". Its value does not change